# How to use ScalarDB in a way that data is stored in DynamoDBLocal?

Tags: scalardb

I believe ScalarDB supports DynamoDB since Version 3.0.0. I would like to use ScalarDB in the form of storing data in DynamoDBLocal. The reason for this is that when we develop as a team, we prepare test data to validate the source code implemented in the local environment, and we want to develop without mixing in test data used by other engineers on the same team while working. We are also concerned that if we store the test data during development in the local environment in AWS DynamoDB, we will incur AWS DynamoDB costs for that.
Is there any way to use ScalarDB with DynamoDBLocal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Scalar DB 3.1, we introduce a configuration "scalar.db.dynamo.endpoint-override" that overrides the endpoint with which the DynamoDB SDK should communicate. You can set this configuration to your DynamoDB Local endpoint to use DynamoDB Local.

Schema Tool for Scalar DB also supports the "--endpoint-override" option to use DynamoDB Local from 3.1.

Scalar DB 3.1:
https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardb/releases/tag/v3.1.0
https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.scalar-labs/scalardb/3.1.0/jar

Answer (score 0):

The CI for Scalar DB on DynamoDB actually uses DynamoDB Local so I think you can simply run your Scalar DB applications on it.